# How to exact match both keys and values in both arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays i want to match exact both keys and values of arrays one of array be three dimensional or more 
Example

```
$arr1 = ['status'=>true,'message'=>'data saved']; 
$arr2 = ['status'=>true,'message'=>'data saved'];
```

in this scenario array return 1 but they are not equal

```
$arr1 = array("messagess"=>"data added","status" => true);
$arr2 = array("status" => true,'message'=>'data has been added'); 
echo count(array_intersect_assoc($arr1,$arr2));
```

Expected should be true if both exact match otherwise false. I have tried array_intersect() and other methods but failed.

Please Guide!

Thank in Advance

Comment: Show the code you tried out. It should not be that hard to write some foreach loop solving this

Comment: *array be three dimensional or more* -- So you might have multidimensional arrays? Should the function also check if the inner arrays are equal, as well?

Comment: To check if the arrays are equal only do if ($arr1===$arr2) {/** matched **/}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use  array_intersect_assoc() and count the resulting number

```
  echo count(array_intersect_assoc($arr1,$arr2));
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-assoc.php

If the number in count is the same of the number of index keys you want  check the the two array are the same otherwise you get the number of key values that match

Comment: but count of this $arr1 = array("messagess"=>"data added","status" => true);
$arr2 = array("status" => true,'message'=>'data has been added');
return 1 should return 0

Comment: 1 is correct  .. in your sample you are looking for 2  .. so one key value match not 2..answer  updated with a brief explanation  .. for more look a t php manual in link